# Gradle 7.2: How to apply a custom Gradle SETTINGS plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am in the process of migrating buildSrc convention plugins into standalone plugins.  There are a lot of examples for creating Gradle plugins for Project objects, but a real dearth for Settings and Gradle.  I want to centralize the list of repositories that we use in our gradle.settings.kts files, so I've created a Gradle Settings plugin: RepositoriesPlugin.

It is implemented in the same manner at a Project plugin, however, I am unsure about how to interpret the following quote from Gradle's docs: "A plugin can instead receive a parameter of type Settings, in which case the plugin can be **applied in a settings script.**", as stated in the documentation at this link: [Gradle 7.2 Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#:%7E:text=A%20plugin%20can%20instead%20receive%20a%20parameter%20of%20type%20Settings%2C%20in%20which%20case%20the%20plugin%20can%20be%20applied%20in%20a%20settings%20script)

The following example shows how I've applied my settings plugin in a settings.gradle.kts file.  **Is this how a settings plugin is applied, as per the documentation?**

I've included the basic settings plugin code, below, too.

I'd appreciate your help to clarify that I am doing this properly.  I am sure that this posting will help others who stray away from just Project plugins.

Thanks for your time and interest..

```
// settings.gradle.kts

pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id("com.abitofhelp.gradle.plugins.repositoriesplugin") version "1.0.0-1"
    }

    settings.extensions
        getByType(RepositoriesPluginExtension::class).apply {
            localRepoName = "local-repo"
            localRepositoryPath = "../../local-repo"
        }

    // Set the plugin repositories for all projects.
    //repositories {
    //    maven { name = "localRepo"; url = uri(file("./local-repo")) }
    //    gradlePluginPortal()
    //    mavenCentral()
    //}
}
```

```
// repositoriesplugin.kt
open class RepositoriesPlugin: Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        val extension: RepositoriesPluginExtension =
            settings.extensions.create("repositoriesPlugin", RepositoriesPluginExtension::class.java)

        val localRepositoryName = extension.localRepositoryName?.let { it }?: "../../localRepo"
        val localRepositoryPath = extension.localRepositoryPath?.let { it }?: "../../local-repo"

        settings.pluginManagement.repositories.apply {
            // Set the PLUGIN REPOSITORIES for all subprojects.
            maven { repository ->
                repository.name = localRepositoryName
                repository.url = URI.create(localRepositoryPath)
            }
            gradlePluginPortal()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        settings.dependencyResolutionManagement.repositories.apply {
            // Set the DEPENDENCY REPOSITORIES for all subprojects.
            maven {
                it.name = localRepositoryName
                it.url = URI.create(localRepositoryPath)
            }
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your question `how to use a plugin from local directory ?` ? because all the path setup seems to be is for repository declaration.

Comment: Hi Prasad, No, The issue is that I have created a Gradle Settings Plugin (not a Project Plugin), and there is no documentation about how to apply/use it with my builds.  Basically, how do I use the Settings Plugin with my settings.gradle.kts file?  Using Project Plugins are simple... :)

Comment: but what  custom behaviour do you need ? above it appears to add maven repo -- this is directly available via gradle settings spec https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management

Comment: Does the [`PluginAware`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html#apply-org.gradle.api.Action-) documentation help? I think in any `settings.gradle.kts` you can activate a plugin with `apply { plugin("my.settings.plugin.id") }`. I think there's a dearth because while Plugins are commonly for Projects, they can be applied to *any* object. It just so happens that Projects have the `plugins {}` block - but that's a special case.

Answer (score 4):

I just had to figure this out myself. You weren't far off with your initial attempt but the `plugins` block actually has to go *after* the `pluginManagement` block. The basic layout of my working implementation looks like this:

```
// settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "myProject"

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("/tmp/maven-local")
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.example.my-plugin") version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Justin Warkentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71448631/10252140) already noted, you *first* need to add your repo in the `pluginManagement` section and *then* you can apply your plugin like any other.

If you want to bypass the repository, you can also add the plugin project as composite build via `includeBuild` in the `pluginManagement` section.

In my example I have combined both methods. If the plugin project exists locally, this one is used, otherwise the version from the repo is used. This way you can (temporarily) add your plugin project to develop on it and test it directly in including projects.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        // your plugin repo; maybe...
        mavenLocal()
    }

    // use local copy of your plugin if available,
    // otherwise load plugin from repo
    def name = 'your_plugin_project'
    if (file(name).isDirectory()) {
        includeBuild(name)
    }
}

plugins {
    // apply your plugin
    id 'your.plugin.id'
}
```

Comment: Didn't realise that I can do `includeBuild` inside `pluginManagement` itself. Saved my day

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the plugin to *settings.gradle classpath* via `buildscript` closure. `pluginManagement.plugins` makes the plugin availabile to the root (& sub) project `build.gradle` classpath, but I think that is a different classpath from the `settings.gradle` script.

To add to settings gradle, give this a try:

```
// settings.gradle
    
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.where.plugin.is.published" }
    }

    classpath("complete.maven.coordinates:your-settings-plugin:version")
}

pluginManager.apply(your.settings.plugin.id)
```