# How can I write a settings plugin as Gradle script

Tags: gradle

I have some code in my `settings.gradle` file to dynamically create references to version catalogs:

```groovy
// list of catalogs is actually loaded from a file
def catalogs = [ "com.example:mycatalog:1.0" ]

dependencyResolutionManagement {

    versionCatalogs {
        catalogs.each { String catalog ->
            def catalogName = catalog.split(":")[1] + "Libs"
            logger.info "Add version catalog ${catalogName} = ${catalog}"
            create(catalogName, { from(catalog) })
        }
    }
}
```

And now I want to share that as a Gradle plugin.

I know that I can write a **project plugin** as a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) with `*.gradle` files in `src/main/groovy` directory.

But then Gradle always builds a `Plugin<Project>` plugin.

How can I declare that I want to a have `Plugin<Settings>` plugin? Or is this not even possible?

Comment: Would this point you in the right direction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149466/gradle-7-2-how-to-apply-a-custom-gradle-settings-plugin